# Imagen no carga sobre HTTP en IONIC

Tags: ionic-framework

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en IONIC y no consigo que me cargue imágenes que van por HTTP. Las de HTTPS van correctamente. El HTML donde las muestro es el siguiente:

```html
<ion-header [translucent]="true">
    <ion-toolbar color="primary">
          <div style="float:left;padding-top: 5px;">
              <ion-title>
                  MeteoRADAR
              </ion-title>        
          </div>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
  
<ion-content class="fondo">
    <div style="width:100%;height:100%">            

        <ion-img src="http://www.cisgalicia.org/contactos/plantillas/20201007_contract/cabecera.png"></ion-img>
        <ion-img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61bhGCoTx2L._AC_SX569_.jpg"></ion-img>
        <img class="object-img" [src]="getImgContent()">
                
    </div>    
</ion-content>
```

La primera y la tercera de las imágenes no se muestran mientras que la segunda si. La tercera imagen es la misma que la primera pero con la URL sanitizada con:

```html
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-radar',
  templateUrl: './radar.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./radar.page.scss'],
})

export class RadarPage {

    url: string;

  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, public sanitizer:DomSanitizer, private route: ActivatedRoute) {

       this.url = "http://www.cisgalicia.org/contactos/plantillas/20201007_contract/cabecera.png";
   }

   getImgContent() {

        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(this.url);
    }   
}
```

Tengo instalado el plugin whitelist y en el config.xml he puesto esto:

```html
access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

También he modificado el index.html para incluir el siguiente meta:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; media-src *; img-src * filesystem: data:">
```

No sé qué más puedo probar! ¿Se os ocurre algo?

Muchas gracias a todos!

Answer (score 0):

¡Solucionado!

Tan solo añadiendo a mi AndroidManifest.xml lo siguiente:

```html
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

y creando (si no existe) o editando el fichero network_security_config.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">www.cisgalicia.org</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```